# Rails - How to call values from one model into another model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I'm working on some app and I have 2 models. Categories in which I create category names and Question. Category has_many questions and Question belongs_to Category. 
I've added category_id to Question model.

Now I need to take all Category_names and display them in form where I create Question so User can choose in which category_name will save question.

I've tried something like this in firs line of code but not working.

```
<%= f.input :category_id, Category.all.map(&:name) %>
<%= f.input :question_name, wrapper: :vertical_text_input, as: :text %>
<%= link_to "Markdown help", "http://assemble.io/docs/Cheatsheet-Markdown.html", target: "_blank", class: "right" %>
<%= f.input :answer %>
<%= f.input :image, as: :attachinary %>
```

**QUESTION: How to display all Category names in form where I create new Questions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may wanna use a select box and use the [collection select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) rails helper :

```
f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name)
```

Comment: It works but when I open page where this form is, it's not showing me collection_select until I refresh page. Then loads select field. Don't know why is this happening..

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this way.

```
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map(&:name), {prompt:"Choose Category"}%>
```

@Jhon suggestion.

```
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.pluck(:name), {prompt:"Choose Category"}%>
```

Comment: `Category.pluck(:name)` is faster than the above